# System calls in Android NDK

Tags: java, android, c++, android-ndk, native

I want use the android NDK to make my c++ engine work on android without having to rewrite the engine in java.

Can system calls for android, for example touch input, accelerometer, windowing and all the other stuff required in most android apps be called from c++? Or do you need to make your own wrapper so the native code can call android java stuff?

If you can is there some kind of API reference to look through for all the possible calls from native code?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Android NDK supplies stable APIs for the following (see http://developer.android.com/tools/sdk/ndk/index.html):

> - libc (C library) headers
> - libm (math library) headers
> - JNI interface headers
> - libz (Zlib compression) headers
> - liblog (Android logging) header
> - OpenGL ES 1.1 and OpenGL ES 2.0 (3D graphics libraries) headers
> - libjnigraphics (Pixel buffer access) header (for Android 2.2 and above).
> - A Minimal set of headers for C++ support
> - OpenSL ES native audio libraries
> - Android native application APIS

Anything else will not be guranteed to work across all devices.
You might also want to take a look at http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/NativeActivity.html for info on how to implement your activity in native code.